# Is it necessary to acquire the lock and notify condition_variable if no thread needs to wake up?

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, condition-variable

I was reading [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) and saw:

> The thread that intends to modify the variable has to
>
> 1. acquire a std::mutex (typically via std::lock_guard)
> 2. perform the modification while the lock is held
> 3. execute notify_one or notify_all on the std::condition_variable (the lock does not need to be held for notification)

If the change doesn't need to wake up threads, like `on_pause` function here, why is acquiring the lock (1) or calling notify (3) necessary? (Just waking them up to say good night?)

```
std::atomic<bool> pause_;
std::mutex pause_lock_;
std::condition_variable pause_event_;

void on_pause() // part of main thread
{
    // Why acquiring the lock is necessary?
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ pause_lock_ };
    pause_ = true;
    // Why notify is necessary?
    pause_event_.notify_all();
}

void on_resume() // part of main thread
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ pause_lock_ };
    pause = false;
    pause_event_.notify_all();
}

void check_pause() // worker threads call this
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ pause_lock_ };
    pause_event_.wait(lock, [&](){ return !pause_; });
}
```

Comment: is this your question:: Why notify is necessary?

Comment: @asmmo Why acquiring the lock is necessary? Why notify is necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `on_pause` function sets `pause_` to true, while the predicate in `check_pause` verifies that it is set to false. Hence calling `notify_all` in `on_pause` is pointless, because the notified threads in `check_pause` will check the predicate and immediately go back to sleep. And since `pause_` is atomic and you don't need to call `notify_all`, you also don't need the lock.